# Why isn't res.redirect actually redirecting me?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a basic login controller with a form that updates the $scope of the user. When they click a button the login() function is triggered.

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.user = {
        'username' : "",
        'password' : ""
    };

    $scope.login = function(){
        $http.post('/login', $scope.user).then(function (response){
            console.log(response.data);
        });

    }

}]);
```

And here is my routing for /login

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res,next){

    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        } else if (!user){
            return res.send(info);
        } else {
            req.logIn(user, function(err){
                if (err){
                    return next(err);
                } else {
                    return res.redirect('/view1');
                }
            });
        }
    })(req,res,next);

});
```

and here is my passport `local-login`.

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true // Allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback function
},
function (req, email, password, done){
    // Checks database via mongoose
    ,function (err,user){
        if (err){
            return done(err);
        } else {
            if (!user){
                return done(null, false, { message : 'No user found.'});
            } else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message : 'Incorrect password'});
            } else {
                return done(null, user);
            }
        }
    });
}));
```

The main problem here is when the `res.redirect('/view1')` is triggered in my routing logic the controller is receiving the html page as the `response.data` instead of actually being redirected. (`$http.post().then(function (response){});`)

If this is incorrect how should I actually be handling the redirecting to `/view1` after the user has successfully logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your are calling the backend from javascript, you basically do an ajax call behind scenes, which will not work with redirects and other HTTP Headers.

In order to redirect the user to the correct page, you have to check the HTTP Status code in the response from your backend and redirect the user to the correct site via angular. Which could look something like this:

```
if(response.status == 302) {
    $window.location.href = '/view1';
}
```

or instead of sending a redirect you can send a status update from the server like:

```
res.json({
    success: true,
    redirectTo: '/view1'
});
```

and parse it on the client:

```
if(response.data.success){
   $window.location.href = response.data.redirectTo;
}
```

Comment: So you're saying instead of doing `return res.redirect('/view1');` I should be doing `return res.status(301)` and then add your code to my `.then(function (response){})` code?

EDIT: Saw your edit, trying this now.

Comment: res.redirect() sends per default an 302 code (fixed in post) (http://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#res.redirect)  and therefore you dont need to change anything on the backend, if you go with this approach

Comment: I went ahead and went with your second method of sending JSON since either way the client will need to handle the request.

1 change I made was updating `$window.location.href = response.data.redirectTo;` to use the angular $location provider. `$location.path(response.data.redirectTo)`