# Redirect from express.js to angular 2 not working (after Passport.js login)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, passport.js

I'm trying to redirect to an angular page after login where the login functions are coded in express.js.

```
router.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
 passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
  }
  if (! user) {
    //return res.send({ success : false, message : 'login failed' });
    res.redirect('/api/login');
  }
  //return res.send({ success : true, message : 'login succeeded' });
  res.redirect('/dashboard');
 })(req, res, next);
});
```

After form submit, the console shows this error:

```
zone.js:2744 GET http://localhost:4200/dashboard 404 (Not Found)

core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…<pre>Cannot GET /dashboard</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}
```

I've commented and checked that the login is successful, and the success redirect fires, but just doesn't redirect. Is this because I'm trying to redirect from express to angular?

I have my route for dashboard set as

```
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});
```

When I manually go to /dashboard, the page loads fine. It just gives a 404 while trying to redirect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is express server and angular app run in different server?

Comment: @DinukaThilanga different ports when on local. But my proxy config handled that. The request goes to the correct post function. Just the redirect isn't working machan :)

Comment: Then you have to use absolute path.

Comment: I did this `res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/dashboard');` and still the same error

Comment: I don't think it reaches the get function for '/dashboard'

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703790/why-isnt-res-redirect-actually-redirecting-me